# Error Trying to get Property of non object (laravel 5.3)

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to access Authenticated user id in AppserviceProvider its working fine when i am in the application mean after once login its work fine but when i logout it gives error and not go to login page

> Trying to get Property of non object

Here is my code of Appserviceprovider written in boot method.

```
public function boot()
{
    view()->composer('*', function($view){
    $view->with('user', Auth::user());

    $counter = DB::table('notifications')->where('notifications.userid', Auth::user()->id)->count();
    View::share('counter', $counter);
    });
```

It gives error in where clause of my above query when i logout . its because after logout its not able to get auth user id..
Please help how can i fix it or how to do it in best way if any

Comment: the problem is this `Auth::user()->id` when you logout `Auth::user()` is empty

Answer (score 0):

You should look into this [Laravel protecting routes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication#protecting-routes)

You can protect routes so they aren't accesible when you're not logged in. This should fix your problem.

If you want this route to be accesible when you're not logged in, you should make an if statement arround the query. You can use `Auth::check()` to see if the user is logged in.

```
if(Auth::check()) {
    //Do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid that when you are logout since `Auth::user()` is empty just use a ternary condition

If `Auth::user()` then use `Auth::user()->id` else if not use `null` value instead

```
Auth::user() ? Auth::user()->id : null
```

change this line

```
$counter = DB::table('notifications')->where('user_notifications.user_id', Auth::user() ? Auth::user()->id : null)->count();
```

Comment: @recoverymen can you `var_dump(Auth::user());` see it's result if you're logout

Comment: but when you're logout is it null or not?

Comment: so it's null did you really use this `Auth::user() ? Auth::user()->id : null` ?

Answer (score 0):

I think your code need to update like:

```
public function boot()
{
    if(Auth::user()){
        view()->composer('*', function($view){
        $view->with('user', Auth::user());

        $counter = DB::table('notifications')->where('user_notifications.user_id', Auth::user()->id)->count();
        View::share('counter', $counter);
        });
   }
```

Hope this work for you!

Comment: its still giving same error .. i cannot use check on start of method because  `$view->with('user', Auth::user());`
 giving me to access auth